# website resolution isn't accurate on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, width

I have a program which runs on localhost and uses chrome in full screen.
When I type into the console

```
window.innerWidth
```

I get the result of 1236. When I do that at any other webpage (not localhost) I get 1360 (as I expected).

I have absolutely no idea why is it. It is really messing up my design since the program is made to work with 1360x768 and 1920x1080.

Any ideas why is it happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`floor(1,360 / 1.1) = 1,236`

You are zoomed in by 10% in your browser for the `localhost` domain. Press Ctrl+0.

Comment: Thanks! It solved the problem! I shall remember that for next time (which hopefully won't be)